# How to parse or locate a string in different line?

Tags: python, string, parsing, scrape

I am new to web scraping and I try to parse a certain content within a file by using a string as a tool to locate the content. The string contains multiple words and in the file, the string has been split into two different lines.

The code I write can no longer locate the string. I have already tried `rstrip()` and `replace()` functions but neither of them works. The example is the following. The image
[image]

is a text file where I highlighted the string `"PRINCIPAL STOCKHOLDER"` I try to locate. As shown in the picture, the string has been split into two lines and the code returns as none since it cannot find the string.

The following code does not work:

```
text_locate = 'PRINCIPAL STOCKHOLDER'
text = (str(text_locate).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: try `' '.join(test.split())` - that will remove all multiple spaces and line breaks and shrinkt them down to 1 space.

Comment: Sorry the code is written by text = ' '.join(test.split())?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = text_locate.strip().replace("\n","")
```

Comment: The problem was not to get rid of the line break and spaces but to locate the string. I need to locate the string then parse the following content. After I locate the string then I can use beautifulsoup  soup.find_all('located_string') to parse the rest of the content. Is there any way I could get my locate string the exact same as the picture showed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the xpath, it's quite simple to use :
https://www.accordbox.com/blog/scrapy-tutorial-7-how-use-xpath-scrapy/

If you don't want to, you can still do that :
https://thispointer.com/python-search-strings-in-a-file-and-get-line-numbers-of-lines-containing-the-string/

Also maybe you should look only for PRINCIPAL or STOCKHOLDER instead of looking for both of them.